# Fix In app purchase for android application

Tags: java, android, firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am new in implanted in app purchase and i have android application by yearly subscription (auto renewal) and faced problem:

The subscriber (active already):
when he opend the application appear alert tell him to subscribe again and appears in our dashboard it’s not active user (unsubscribe)
Then after he press subscribe again the system tells him (error) you are already subscribed, Then (appear active in dashboard).
is it the problem from backend in our server? Or from our billing library ? Or must be make restore button? Or Is there another solution?

I didn’t know why the app. ask him to pay again for subscription, because he already subscribed and active? in this moment: he became not active in our dashboard, Then when he pressed again to subscribe (you are already subscribed) after that he became active in our dashboard.

Comment: Without any of your code attached, we can't help you much...

Comment: You are right ,, but i do my best to help the developer company who’s working in my app .. because they didn’t have much experience in app purchase. I hope to know the Possible possibilities for this problem to occurring  , please